# running "netdom query fsmo" on domain controller fails

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

When running the command "netdom query fsmo" on any of my Windows 2008 R2 domain controllers the command returns the error "The command failed to complete successfully".  If I run the command on a regular (non domain controller) server, in the same domain, the command runs fine.  Is this by design or do I have a problem on my domain controllers?

Comment: `Is this by design or do I have a problem on my domain controllers?` - That command should list the FSMO role holders when run from a Domain Controller. Check the Directory Service and DNS Server event logs, followed by the Application and System event logs for clues.

Comment: I get the same thing on my windows 2008R2 server that is in my test site. This seems to have happened after I ran yesterdays updates on it. It does not happen on my production domain controller.

Comment: I have the same file dates between the working domain and the test domain. They are each a day off from yours but that is a time zone thing I am sure. I would not have even noticed it but I am testing upgrading my domain and had this problem and went searching for an answer.

Comment: Ran the command again and checked all the logs.  Nothing gets logged in the event logs when the command returns the failure message.

Comment: I wonder if netdom.exe was updated with this and it broke something? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4490425/updates-to-tgt-delegation-across-incoming-trusts-in-windows-server

Answer (score 1):

Just had this on my Windows2008r2 DC as well, after updating yesterday.

From what I can see it was the `netdom.exe` file that was messing it up. I restore the old one from a backup file and now it's working again.

See the image below, the one with date 22-02-2019 doesn't work, the one from 2009 works

[image: screenshot of the 2 netdom.exe files]

Comment: I suspected it might have something to do with the recent updates.  I wonder if Microsoft is aware of this issue yet.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this happened on one of my servers too. I'm running windows server 2008R2.

netdom.exe was updated by a windows update on 3-13-2019 with a new version of the file with a 2/21/2019 file date from a 7/13/2009 file date.

the new netdom.exe would not run " netdom query fsmo ".

I recovered the older file from a backup and then ran the command and it worked correctly.

So there is something wrong from this update of netdom.exe .

the file I recovered was the one in " c:\windows\system32 "